# Where to place pmx attributes in a pm2 managed node app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, pm2

I have deployed a node app onto heroku with pm2. Since we dont have a console to deploy pm2 has provided an official way of using another file[main.js] as a startup script abstraction

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/#heroku-google-app-engine-azure

The question is where the pmx statements[shown below] should go; on the node project app.js or the pm2 abstraction main.js as mentioned in above link?

```
var pmx = require('pmx').init({
  http          : true, // HTTP routes logging (default: true)
  ignore_routes : [/socket\.io/, /notFound/], // Ignore http routes with this pattern (Default: [])
  errors        : true, // Exceptions loggin (default: true)
  custom_probes : true, // Auto expose JS Loop Latency and HTTP req/s as custom metrics
  network       : true, // Network monitoring at the application level
  ports         : true  // Shows which ports your app is listening on (default: false)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your project app.js. The *pm2 abstraction main.js* is only there to launch PM2 and link it to Keymetrics